# Run-time error when retrieving value from FormControl ListBox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, form-control

I added a `FormControl` `ListBox` with the name `ListBox2` to an Excel worksheet and I assigned a Macro `RectangleRoundedCorners3_Click` to a shape. Now I would like to print the first item of the list box into cell A1:

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners3_Click()

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = ActiveSheet.ListBox1.List(0)

End Sub
```

I get the following error:

> Run-time error '438':
>
> Object doesn't support this property or method

I don't really understand why this happens. If I use an `ActiveX Controls` `ListBox` the exact same code works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = Activesheet.ListBoxes("ListBox2").List(1)
```

Note: a reference to the `ActiveSheet` is not the best way to reference a sheet. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/9758194) post here to read more about it.

A helpful overview of `FormControl ListBoxes` using several methods can be found at the site [Complete guide to Excel VBA Form Control ListBoxes](https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/complete-guide-to-excel-vba-form-control-listboxes/). - Edited due to Jonas' comment :-)

Comment: Works! Thank you a lot! I will check out the link too. Thanks

Comment: Helpful link [](https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/complete-guide-to-excel-vba-form-control-listboxes/)

Comment: @T.M. a very helpfull link. feel free to edit into the answer =)